# How to calculate the number bracket a given number falls within a set of numbers?

Tags: math

I have a contiguous set of numbers up to a maximum (1...y). Im trying to find in which increment (defined by another value x) a given number (z) falls within that set.

Below is an image that best describes what I'm trying to find.

[image]

Is there a formula I can use with the available information to achieve this?

Comment: F(18)=2, and F(24)=3. What about F(10)?

Comment: F(30) must equal 3 therefore - F(20) = 2, F(10) = 1

If that helps.

Comment: And are you familiar with the ceiling function?

Comment: I only see Ceil being helpful if the above image was the exact data set im working with (the image is only an example set). Im looking for a formula that can be applied to any set. If we change the set upper bounds to say 50, then I dont see how Ceil helps. Please correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = ceil(z*x/y);
```

In your example, the size of the range is divisible by the number of bins, so that all bins have equal size. If that condition does not hold then there may be some further questions about edge cases.

Comment: Thank you for shedding some light on this for me.